# How can I (and should I?) acceptance test a simple Flask app without importing unnecessary libraries?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm relatively new to Python and entirely new to Flask. I'm trying to create a Flask app that at least initially consists of little more than a couple of forms, some number crunching based on the values you submit and then a page displaying the outcome. It will probably never have a database.

The in-progress version based on the Flask 'getting started' guide plus importing the logic, looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pdb

import calculators.simple_calc.simple_calc as sc
from calculators.website.forms.simple_calc import SimpleCalcForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'seekrit'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def simple_calc_page():
  form = SimpleCalcForm()
  calc = None
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    calc = sc.SimpleCalc(request.form)
  return render_template('simple_calc_page.html', form=form, calc=calc)
```

And this works fine. But when I look up guides to acceptance testing in Flask, eg [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-pytest/) and [this](https://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I end up down a rabbithole: we start with a create_app() function, which the docs haven't mentioned until now. Looking at the [guide for that](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/appfactories/), I'm still unsure where to put the function (GPT tells me in the `__init__.py` file, but that instruction seems to have been removed from all the docs in which GPT found it), or where to call it from; and it's now telling me to import a further library, Blueprint, just to create this file.

This all feels very complicated for what I'm trying to do. Should I nonetheless do it anyway? If so, where *should* I put the create_app() function, and where should I call it from? Or is it better to stick with a simpler approach? And if so, how do I actually do acceptance testing?

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, your code **shouldn't** contain stuff that isn't relevant to running the code. This applies to all languages (not just Python/Flask). And to speed up loading your program/program execution, you should generally initialize variables or packages **only** when they're needed and not just blindly at the beginning of your program.
2. When you run flask from the command line, you **can** tell it where to locate your application by specifying an `-app` flag. I used **'can'** to indicate the flag is optional. If you **don't specify the flag**, flask will try to automatically detect your `app` object.

   According to [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/cli/)

   > The name “app” or “wsgi” is imported (as a “.py” file, or package), automatically detecting an app (app or application) or factory (create_app or make_app).
3. You can also specify a value for the `--app` flag by just supplying the name of the file e.g. `--app hello`. Same documentation as above has this

   > The given name is imported, automatically detecting an app (app or application) or factory (create_app or make_app).

   This means it will look for `hello.py` and follow the logic above to get the `app` object.
4. A very simple explanation is -

   a) you can specify `app` object directly at a global level in your main file like the way you've done it and when you run your App, flask will detect it.

   b)  or you can put the `app` object within a `create_app` function (like the example you linked to) and when you run it, flask will also find it from the `create_app` function